# Rails - get date from date & time stamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails database, I have a timestamp that looks like this `2010-12-22 18:21:46 UTC`. I need a way to just get the date `2010-12-22` from it without re-doing the database.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try `time.to_date` to extract date component from your timestamp.

Comment: You can also add `to_s` (for example `your_datetime.to_date.to_s`) so that it converts it from something like *Tue, 20 Dec 2016* to *"2016-12-20"* which seems to be what you were looking for initially.

Comment: If you're not sure the datetime field won't be nil you should add a `.try()`. Like `your_datetime.try(:to_date)`. That way if `your_datetime` is nil this will just return nil (instead of an error).

Answer (score 18):

To get the `String` you're looking for

```
your_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Not sure what you mean about modifying the database?

Comment: what to do to get the time alone

Comment: Look at the documentation here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime You can use e.g. `your_date.strftime("%H : %M")`

Answer (score 1):

To get the String you're looking for

```
your_date.strftime("%F")
```

below link u can get more type of date.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime